# How do I convert rows as columns while reading from a file?

Tags: java

How can I read and convert file stream below

0101011110
0000011010
0000001011
1000011000

write as below;

0001
1000
0000
1000
0000
1101
1111
1000
1110
0010

ArrayList does not sustain my requirements, it collapsed after a few trials.
I have 100k rows and 40 columns within my file. After reading line by line as strings, I do not know what to do as a newbie I tried this:

```
 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        String sequence;
        while((sequence= instream.readLine())!= null) {
            list.add(sequence);  
        }
        Iterator<String> it=list.iterator();
        for(int i=0; i<40; i++){
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String temp=  it.next();
            outstream.write(temp.charAt(i)+" ");    
        }
        outstream.newLine();
      }
```

---

This does the work!

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String sequence;

        while ((sequence = instream.readLine()) != null)
            list.add(sequence);

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            for (String item : list) {
                outstream.write(item.charAt(i) + " ");
            }
            outstream.newLine();
        }
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Are you able to simply read the whole file into memory? That would certainly simplify matters...

Comment: Yes, i am able to read the whole file

Comment: A simple solution would be using a 2d array. Then you wouldn't have to convert rows to columns. You can just refer to desired element as [j][i] instead of [i][j].

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it in the following steps:

1. Read the file line by line into an ArrayList<String>. Verify that all the lines
   are the same length (or determine the length of the longest one) as you go.
2. For each position on the line, iterate through the list of lines, printing the character at the current position. When you finish the list, print a newline.

Comment: +1 Since it's a homeworky question, the complete answer as a rule can not be given and you suggested the best.